# Empty out a Meteor database/collection after a certain number?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can say I'm new to JS but have a grasp on how everything works - but I recently tried jump into meteor and it seems to just cut out most of the code for shortcuts which I have trouble understanding.

I'm trying to empty out the **first half** of a meteor database once it hits a certain number of items, in this case 100. I only have:

```
var printOut = MongoDatabase.find().count(); 

if (printOut > 100) {
    //delete first 50 entries of the 100 items
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The "first half" according to what? Creation date? And what have you tried to achieve this, where did you fail?

Comment: @Kyll Creation date but I can't find the function to actually take out certain items in the collection that isn't using the 'id' one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find a cutoff for CreationDate, then remove all before that date:

```
if (MongoDatabase.find().count() > 100){
  cutoff = MongoDatabase.find({}, {fields: {CreationDate: 1, _id: 0}, sort: {CreationDate: -1 }, limit: 50}).fetch().pop().CreationDate
  MongoDatabase.remove({CreationDate: {$lt: cutoff}})
}
```

This will work on the server, but if you try to do this directly on the client you will get the following error:

```
"Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]"
```

So if you need to trigger this from the client, using a Meteor.Method would be the best way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also managed to find this: https://teamgaslight.com/blog/how-to-remove-all-elements-from-a-meteor-collection